# How can i retrieve database name into Magento?

Tags: database

i'm going to clean an hosting where different databases and magento sites exist. My target is to delete everything but the one i need. The problem is that database manager prompts me different database (5), 2 of them are not connected to my magento choosed installation, the others 3 seems to be equals. I tried to explore tables that could help me, like admin_user and core_config_data, but those 3 databases seems to be the same themselves. My question is: how can i retrieve the database currently used by my installation in Magento? Another question is: these 3 dbs could be connected each other?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to check the `local.xml` file in `app/etc/`. The database name should be listed around the middle of the file and should list the database name as well as other useful info.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably quicker to just look in to env.php in the same directory, database is at top, virtually the first entry.